# como construir esta vista personalizada ?

Tags: android

Como puedo contruir esta vista, si teoricamente cada buton es una imagen, pero esta claro que las imagenes por default son cuadradas, por lo que no funcionaria, se les ocurre como podria crear la vista?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Gilberto! Recuerda en traducir tu pregunta o será cerrada por estar en inglés! :D

Comment: Con imagenes transparentes? (la parte negra con semitransparencia)

Answer (score 2):

Buenas Gilberto,

En la carpeta `res/drawable/` de tu proyecto puedes definir mediante un archivo xml estilos y figuras. Por ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="hexagon">
 <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
 <size android:width="60dp"
    android:height="40dp" />
</shape>
```

Este ejemplo crearía un hexagono como el de arriba, luego en el layout donde tengas el `Button` puedes definirle el estilo creado mediante `android:background="@drawable/mi_estilo".`

[Aquí](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) tienes un enlace para que veas todas las propiedades que puedes darle a las figuras y estilos.

Espero que te ayude mas o menos por donde tirar.

Saludos!